# SDDM on Wayland crashes in test mode

Tags: qemu, kvm, wayland, arch, weston

I am trying SDDM on Wayland in a VM but I am not able to get it to work.
My system maybe is a little unusual:
The host is a Mac Mini (old one - Late 2012) on which I run Ubuntu 23.04
[image: Host system]

On this I run QEMU/KVM and a VM with Arch Linux and refind as UEFI bootloader:
[image: Guest system]

With yay/pacman I have installed: `wayland xwayland sddm-git weston`
Then I copied SDDM config file from `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/default.conf` to `/etc/sddm.conf.d/` and changed from `DisplayServer=X11` to `DisplayServer=wayland`

Then I run `sudo sddm --test`
[image: SDDM crash]

If I try `sudo sddm-greeter --test-mode`
[image: sddm-greeter crash]

I don't know if these errors are related or two different issues.

The WM weston works just fine when run from cli. I haven't configured weston at all, so I assume it is using wayland.
[image: WM weston]

If I change back to `DisplayServer=X11` `sddm --test`works fine. I assume then it is using xwayland since I haven't installed X11.

The only thing I can see in log files is some issue with ´/dev/tty1´.

The journal:
[image: journal log]

/var/log/sddm.log:
[image: SDDM log]

/var/log/Xorg.0.log:
[image: X11 log]

Any ideas how to proceed? Maybe this is not even a problem with SDDM or wayland, but something else that is miss-configured in my system?

I tried to change the way SDDM invokes weston, but that didn´t change anything.

Since I installed ´sddm-git´ maybe I can build SDDM in debug and debug it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ might be more appropriate for this sort of question

Comment: @SamMason Good suggestion, I've posted the question over on https://superuser.com/questions/1806397/sddm-on-wayland-crashes-in-test-mode as well.